# How to stop family members from giving me pictures of their children?

Tags: family, germany, gifts

I want to know how to politely ask family members to not give me pictures of their children.

Every year I try to find suitable presents for my family members only to receive the exact same present year after year. This happens on every occasion where presents are exchanged. It's close family like my sisters and aunts.

Comment: are you trying to get a different present?

Comment: Is this for a specific occasion like Christmas? What exactly is your family relation to these people? Is much thought / trouble put into the pictures?

Comment: Have you ever tried anything already to show/tell them you're not interested? Or, in case you haven't, what have you thought of doing and why are you not doing that? Is it a custom to gift pictures in your family, or do other family members get other gifts? Can you take a look at [our meta post on writing good questions](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/1599), and [edit] in additional details?

Comment: Also, a closely related question: [How can I communicate to friends and family that I don't want a specific type of birthday gift?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/11962/1599), this might even be a duplicate

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate, as the problem of telling people you don't want a common default gift item is much simpler than the complicated issue of telling family members that you don't want to display pictures of their kids in your house.